# how to fix grub for dual boot after installing windows 8?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, encryption

i ran in dualboot an encrypted ubuntu 16.04lts with a windows 8.1..after reinstalling windows i lost the grub menu..i tried fixing it by running bootrepair using recommended repair button but it didnt work..i think because the partition is encrypted.

from a live cd :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.3 GiB, 1433468928 bytes, 2799744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8448020a

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 567158783 567156736 270.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       567158784 568135679    976896   477M 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       568137726 764157951 196020226  93.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda4       771971445 976768064 204796620  97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       568137728 764157951 196020224  93.5G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4089970688 bytes, 7988224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00255f71

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 7988223 7986176  3.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/mapper/encrypted-volume: 93.5 GiB, 100360257536 bytes, 196016128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

the sda4:noname3 is a partition without any OS, and 
the sda1 has the windows 8.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                 8:1    0 270.5G  0 part  
├─sda2                 8:2    0   477M  0 part  /mnt
├─sda3                 8:3    0     1K  0 part  
├─sda4                 8:4    0  97.7G  0 part  /media/ubuntu/NoName3
└─sda5                 8:5    0  93.5G  0 part  
  └─encrypted-volume 252:0    0  93.5G  0 crypt 
sdb                    8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                 8:17   1   3.8G  0 part  /cdrom
sr0                   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
loop0                  7:0    0   1.3G  1 loop  /rofs
```

here are the errors i ran to :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'. 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 encrypted-volume
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda5:
Cannot use device /dev/sda5 which is in use (already mapped or mounted)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgchange -ay
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvscan
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls /dev/mapper/
control  encrypted-volume
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/sda5 /mnt/system/
mount: special device /dev/mapper/sda5 does not exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/system/boot/
mount: mount point /mnt/system/boot/ does not exist

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/sda5 /mnt
mount: special device /dev/mapper/sda5 does not exist

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
```

i got to be honest i am a noob when it comes to linux but i really enjoyed working with ubuntu this past 2 years..i hope someone can help me fix it..thank you in advance.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

You have a tiny bit of a mess when it comes to your hard disk configuration. Be aware that encryption can cause lots of backup/restore problems, so if you don't really need encryption, don't use it. Also, I'm also guessing that you only have a small amount of RAM, and the use of ramdisk software probably isn't helping you either.

Your smallish sda shows two Linux partitions (why?), and two ntfs partitions (why?), no swap (unless you're using /swapfile), and your extended and 2nd ntfs partition are not properly aligned...

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8448020a

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 567158783 567156736 270.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       567158784 568135679    976896   477M 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       568137726 764157951 196020226  93.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda4       771971445 976768064 204796620  97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       568137728 764157951 196020224  93.5G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

If it was me... I'd...

- backup your Windows and Ubuntu data
- lay down a fresh MBR partition table (**this will wipe the disk**)
- reinstall Windows FIRST
- reinstall Ubuntu SECOND
- re-run `sudo fdisk -l` and confirm no misaligned partitions
- be happy